# how many default number of partition there are when I initially start my spark application

Tags: apache-spark

I ran a spark application with intellij IDEA in order to test the question that how spark distribute and allocate the partitions of RDD. The code was:

```
object Tuning {

  PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/log4j.properties")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val master = args.length match {
      case x: Int if x > 0 => args(0)
      case _ => "local[4]"
    }
    val sf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("tuning")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sf)
    val inputRDD = sc.textFile("files/sfpd.csv")
    val sfpdRDD = inputRDD.map(x => x.split(","))
    val catRDD = sfpdRDD.map(x => (x(1), 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
    println("partition number: " + catRDD.getNumPartitions)
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    catRDD.collect()
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time01: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    val t2 = System.nanoTime()
    catRDD.collect()
    val t3 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time02: " + (t3 - t2) + "ns")
    val t4 = System.nanoTime()
    catRDD.count()
    val t5 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time03: " + (t5 - t4) + "ns")
    val a = catRDD.repartition(10)
    println("partition number: " + a.getNumPartitions)
    val t6 = System.nanoTime()
    a.collect()
    val t7 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time04: " + (t7 - t6) + "ns")
    val t8 = System.nanoTime()
    a.collect()
    val t9 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time05: " + (t9 - t8) + "ns")
    val t10 = System.nanoTime()
    a.count()
    val t11 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time06: " + (t11 - t10) + "ns")
    val t12 = System.nanoTime()
    val b =a.coalesce(4)
    println("partition number: " + b.getNumPartitions)
    b.collect()
    val t13 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time07: " + (t13 - t12) + "ns")
    val t14 = System.nanoTime()
    b.collect()
    val t15 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time08: " + (t15 - t14) + "ns")
    val t16 = System.nanoTime()
    b.count()
    val t17 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time09: " + (t17 - t16) + "ns")
  }
}
```

I supposed that the output of print code

```
println("partition number: " + catRDD.getNumPartitions)
```

should be

```
partition number: 4
```

because, I locally run the application on 4 cores. But, It is really:

```
partition number: 2
```

I don't understand why. I think the default number of partition should be equal with the number of cores. Spark will run one task for each partition of the cluster. Typically you want 2-4 partitions for each CPU in your cluster. I suppose that it is efficient that the both of number is equal at default situation.

Now, I inserted the codes in the above spark application:

```
val parallel01 = sc.parallelize(1 to 9)
println("parallel01 partition number: " + parallel01.getNumPartitions)
```

the result showed：

```
parallel01 partition number: 4
```

this number is right and what I expected. It is interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set executor cores?

`spark.executor.cores` :1 in YARN mode, all the available cores on the worker in standalone and Mesos coarse-grained modes

This documentation [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)may address your query:

`spark.default.parallelism`:

> For distributed shuffle operations like reduceByKey and join, the largest number of partitions in a parent RDD.

For operations like parallelize with no parent RDDs, it depends on the cluster manager:

`Local mode:` number of cores on the local machine

`Mesos fine grained mode:` 8

`Others:` *total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2, whichever is larger*

Comment: Those information that you provided are very great. But, I still am not clear about the problem of Local Mode. The numbers of partitions should be equal with the number of cores on the local machine. This testing application showed the confusing result, the both methods of parallelize and textFile produced deferent number of partitions. I want to know why. thank you

Comment: Unless you configure executor cores, Spark won't use them. SPARK won't use all cores available in machine unless it was directed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,When I ran respectively this application with the different parameter, such as local[*], local, local[1], local[4], the partitions of inputRDD are equal to 2. The cores of computer running application is 2. Then I inserted the additional codes to test:

```
val parallel01 = sc.parallelize(1 to 9)
println("parallel01 partition number: " + parallel01.getNumPartitions)
```

The partitions of parallel01 were respectively equal to 2, 1, 1, 2. So, I figured out that the usage of local parameter would have some interesting hidden rules. first of all, the default number of partitions which the textFile() used was not less than 2. Secondly, local[*] meant to use all cores of computer, local did 1 core. local[4] did not work because the cores is 2.